# what is the purpose of the function annotation method in the Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, annotations, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm starting using facebook javscript SDK, and I found a interesting thing when I read the source code.

The code example is as belowed:

```
/**
 * Annotates a function with a meta object
 */
function annotate(fn, meta) {
    meta.superClass = fn.__superConstructor__;
    fn.__TCmeta = meta;
    return fn;
}

// export to global
__w = annotate;

/**
 * when using the annotate function
 */
function sprintf(format) {
   // function body
}
__w(sprintf, {"signature":"function(string)"});   // <-- what is the purpose of doing this?
```

So, my question is what is that used for? What is the **benefit** doing this?

FYI, the whole source code is here, where you can see lots of annotate() is being used

http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote and close vote, it's an interesting question and within the scope of SO. I'm also quite curious why Facebook is doing this.

Comment: If anyone wants me to expand on what's already been mentioned, I'd be happy to :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a home-grown strong typing setup:

```
/**
 * A recursive descent analyzer which takes a value and a typehint, validating
 * whether or not the value matches the typehint.
 * The function will call it self as long as both the value and the typehint
 * yields a nested component. This means that we will never recurse deeper
 * than needed, and also that we automatically get support for
 *   > equals([], 'array<string>') // true
 *   > equals(['string'], 'array') // true
 */
function equals(value, node) {
  var type = typeof value;
  var subType;
  var nextNode;
  var nextValue;

  //: Nullable types are delimited with a leading ?
  //: ?string, ?boolean, etc.
  var nullable = /^\?/.test(node);
  if (nullable) {
    node = node.substring(1);
  }

//: snip ...

switch (type) {
  // start by testing the most common types
  case 'boolean':
  case 'number':
  case 'string':
  case 'undefined':
    break;
  default:
      //: snip ...
      // let functions with signatures also match 'function'
      type = value.__TCmeta && node !== 'function'
        ? value.__TCmeta.signature
        : 'function';
    } else if (type === 'object' || type === 'function') {
      // HTMLObjectElements has a typeof function in FF
      var constructor = value.constructor;
      if (constructor && constructor.__TCmeta) {
        // The value is a custom type
        //: snip ...
          while (constructor && constructor.__TCmeta) {
            if (constructor.__TCmeta.type == node) {
              type = node;
              break;
            }
            constructor = constructor.__TCmeta.superClass;
          }
        //: snip ...
        }
      }
    }
}

if (nullable && /undefined|null/.test(type)) {
  return true;
}

if (type in typeInterfaces) {
  var interfaces = typeInterfaces[type], i = interfaces.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (interfaces[i] === node) {
      type = node;
      break;
    }
  }
}

currentType.push(type);
return nextValue && nextNode
  ? node === type && equals(nextValue, nextNode)
  : subType && nextNode
    ? node === type && subType === nextNode
    : node === type;
}
```

```
/**
 * Given a value and a typehint (can be a union type), this will return
 * whether or not the passed in value matches the typehint.
 */
function matches(value, node) {
  var nodes = node.split('|'), i = nodes.length;
  while (i--) {
    currentType = [];
    if (equals(value, nodes[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The reason they use the `annotate` function is to allow type hinting for *custom* types and function signatures.  Without `annotate` you could only do `matches(someVar, "function")`.  With `annotate` you can do `matches(someVar, "function(string, ?int)|function(string)")` and only accept functions that take a string and a nullable `integer` or functions that only accept a string.

Comment: Thanks. The matches() function (whose alias is __t in the source code), is to do function parameters type check. But this question is to ask the purpose of __w.  @SeanVieira

Comment: @user1481096 - I've added some more explanation around `annotate`.  Let me know if I can do anything further to assist!

Comment: Not static (at least not this part of it), but strong dynamic typing.

Comment: Thanks @SeanKinsey for the clarification! Do I take it, from your comment that there are parts of the JS codebase that are statically checked?